Calling a batch file from PowerShell Start-Process immediately exits with no exit code or warning
I have a bat file with a single argument that runs perfectly from a command prompt:
D:\Program Files\Server\tools\createsite>createsite.bat -f D:\Stage\createsite.properties

But from within PowerShell the following:
Start-Process -FilePath $ENV:ComSpec -ArgumentList "/c D:\Program Files\Server\tools\createsite\createsite.bat -f D:\Stage\createsite.properties"

Immediately exits with no exit code or warning. Suspecting it was execution policy I've set that to Undefined: same behavior.
Start-Process -FilePath $ENV:ComSpec -ArgumentList "/c D:\Program Files\Server\tools\createsite\createsite.bat -f D:\Stage\createsite.properties" -Verb runas

Also produces the same result.

You need to surround the path to the batch file with escaped quotes, as the first portion contains a space character. See Example 7 at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4.

Using the escaped quotes: "Start-Process -FilePath "$ENV:ComSpec" -ArgumentList "/c dir "'D:\Program Files\Server\tools\createsite\createsite.bat' -f D:\Stage\createsite.properties"" I now get "Start-Process : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'FilePath' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".". The argument for this specific bat file is the path to a properties file.

As an aside:  execution policies are a PowerShell-specific concept and therefore do not apply to batch files.



Generally, there is no good reason to use Start-Process to run a batch file from PowerShell:

To synchronously execute batch files (and console applications) in the current console (terminal), call them directly
(& 'D:\Program Files\Server\tools\createsite\createsite.bat' in the case at hand). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via $LASTEXITCODE. See this answer and this guidance with respect to when Start-Process is and isn't appropriate.


If you do need to use Start-Process, after all (e.g. to run the batch file in a new console window) pass the batch-file path as the -FileName argument: batch files are special in that they are recognized as executable files, even though they aren't in a strict sense (ultimately, they must be processed via cmd.exe /c):
# Runs the batch file in a new window that will automatically
# close afterwards.
# To make Start-Process wait until the batch file terminates, add -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath 'D:\Program Files\Server\tools\createsite\createsite.bat' -ArgumentList '-f D:\Stage\createsite.properties'



